# Chrome extension keyboard command firing twice when popup is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the following Chrome extension, I receive a keyboard command twice when the shortcut is pressed, but only when the browser popup is open. Here's how you replicate it:

1. Install the following chrome extension.
2. Navigate to the Chrome extensions page
3. Scroll to the bottom and click "Keyboard shortcuts"
4. Set the shortcut for the extension to Alt+Shift+S
5. In the extensions page, click the "background page" link for the extension to open the background page console.
6. Hit Alt+Shift+S. You'll see "command" being logged once.
7. Now open the browser popup that should have appeared when the extension was installed. Hit Alt+Shift+S.
8. Go to the background page console and you'll see "command" logged twice.

Here is the code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "commands": {
        "command": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Alt+Shift+S"
            },
            "description": "My command"
        }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    console.log(command);
});
```

popup.html does not need to exist. Why is this happening? I have a hack where I don't accept commands if it's been less than 50 ms since the last command, but I don't want to use a hack.

Comment: What's in `popup.html` ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem The result is the same whether or not `popup.html` does or doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist nothing loads in the popup which is fine.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have a clue :) I can't test it myself because I am not on the dev channel (but I believe you). The only possible cause I can think of is that the shortcut is "captured" by both the popup and the browser window, so it is triggering the listener twice - but of course this is pure speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with the GTK build of Chrome. You can see the bug report I filed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=355559

This will not be fixed in the GTK build since Chrome is switching to Aura anyway.